# ios location manager firing even when distance specified by distancefilter is not hit

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager

can someone please tell me why im getting location updates every two steps or so when my distance filter is set to 30 metres?

```
- (void)initLocationTrackingStandard 
{
    [self.locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:YES];
    [self.locationManager setActivityType:CLActivityTypeOther];
    [self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:30.0];
    [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations 
{
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (abs(howRecent) < 5.0)
    {
        // Use location if it is within 5 seconds
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.alertBody = @"update location";
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
    }
}
```

Comment: I've only ever used kCLDistanceFilterNone before, so I don't know if what you're seeing is *normal* or not, but my first inkling has to do with accuracy.. What is the accuracy of those updates? I would log them to compare. I can imagine that two locations with distances between each other less than 30 meters could *seem* far enough away if their accuracies were say something like 60m each?